# Pass dynamic data from Scaffold body to Navigation Drawer in Flutter (using Drawer as side sheet)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a counter app which supports multiple counters. Since flutter does not provide a side sheet modal, I am using the Navigation Drawer as a side sheet.

I have a Scaffold with a GridView of Cards in its body. These cards each have a name and a counter value. Whenever one of the cards is tapped, the Navigation Drawer is opened and it should display the person's name and the count value. In this Drawer, there is also a button to increment the counter value corresponding to the clicked Card. However, the problem is, how do I pass data from the Scaffold body to the Drawer? I can open the Drawer programmatically using `Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();` but that does not allow me to pass data to it.

I can also use the code below, which does allow me to pass data, but then the Drawer is opened like a page and it overlays the full screen.

```
Navigator.push(
  context, 
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => TurfDrawer(name: name, count: count)
  ));
```

So basically, I just want to know which Card was clicked and pass that to the Drawer. All help is much appreciated.

The Scaffold looks like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      // App bar
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Turflijst'),
        elevation: 0.0, 
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.settings), onPressed: null)
        ],
      ),

      // Drawer
      endDrawer: TurfDrawer(),

      // Body
      body: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Stack(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
            children: <Widget> [
              Container(
                color: primaryColor,
                height: (kEffectHeight - offset * 2.5).clamp(0.0, kEffectHeight),
              ),
              Positioned(
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 70),
                  width: 1200.0,
                  child: GridView.count(
                    controller: scrollController,
                    crossAxisCount: 4,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                    childAspectRatio: 2,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      for (MapEntry entry in list.asMap().entries) 
                        TurfCard(index: entry.key, name: entry.value, count: count[entry.key])
                    ]
```

And this is the Card:

```
class TurfCard extends StatefulWidget {

  final int index, count;
  final String name;
  TurfCard({
    Key key, 
    @required this.index, 
    @required this.name, 
    @required this.count
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TurfCardState createState() => _TurfCardState();
}

class _TurfCardState extends State<TurfCard> {

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    return GridTile(
      child: Card(
        elevation: 1.5,
        color: Colors.white,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
        child: InkWell(
          splashColor: primaryColor.withAlpha(100),
          onTap: () {
            Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
            // Navigator.push(
            //   context, 
            //   MaterialPageRoute(
            //     builder: (context) => TurfDrawer()
            //   ));
            print('Card $widget.index tapped.');
          },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I solved this using a ChangeNotifier from the provider package. Whenever a Card is clicked, the value in the ChangeNotifier is updated and updates its listeners. The Drawer then listens to this ChangeNotifier.

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution:

You save the selected index as a field in the ScaffoldWidget class (whatever you called it):

```
class TurfCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function() onTap;
//...other properties
}
class _TurfCardState extends State<TurfCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SomeWidgets(
      child: InkWell(
        //...
        onTap: widget.onTap,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  int selectedIndex; //you can also save the index here and update it in onTap()
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Widget build(BuildContext context){
      return Scaffold(
        //...
          body: SomeWidgets(
            //...
          for(MapEntry entry in list.asMap().entries)
          TurfCard(
          //some properties....
          onTap:(){
               selectedIndex = entry.key;
               Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
              print('Card ${entry.key tapped.');
               }
           )
        ),
      ),
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Then how do I use this selectedIndex inside my Drawer widget?

Comment: store it in a field inside the widget that opens the drawer
see the updated answer

Comment: By making selectedIndex static and accessing it in the Drawer using HomePage.selectedIndex? Is that a recommended way of passing data between widgets?

Comment: I did not mention static in any place,look at the code above it is a simple int,for more complex scenarios of sharing data between widgets you would like to use another solution like provider package for example

Comment: Okay, maybe I am too much of a Flutter noob to understand this then. How am I able to access selectedIndex from my Drawer class if it is not static? Thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: where are you defining the turfdrawer? if in the same class as the scaffold (i.e. HomePage) then you can access the index as it is a field of that class,I can't suggest more since I don't know how the TurfDrawer is

Comment: It is defined in a different class in a different file.
`class TurfDrawer extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _TurfDrawerState createState() => _TurfDrawerState();
}

class _TurfDrawerState extends State<TurfDrawer> {
  int _amount = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
       // Some widgets
    );
  }
}`

Then it is added to the Scaffold using its endDrawer property `endDrawer: TurfDrawer()`